# Shortening my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I make this jQuery shorter? I assume there must be a better way of working than this!?

(bare in mind I am new to jQuery)...

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    var White = jQuery("#white").hide();
    jQuery("#firstpagename").on("click", function() {
        White.toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    var Black2 = jQuery("#v2black").hide();
    jQuery("#secondpagename").on("click", function() {
        Black2.toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    var Black3 = jQuery("#v3black").hide();
    jQuery("#thirdpagename").on("click", function() {
        Black3.toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help or directions would be greatt as I am down to the last step on this site and want it finished :)

Comment: Can you post your html? Since you are using `on`, can we make the assumption that you are loading dynamic content?

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: @mrtsherman: He's not using `on()` the way it should be used for dynamic elements, so that assumption is invalid.

Comment: @Purmou no, but it's not explicit that they're dynamic elements. That's a perfectly valid syntax for `.on()` if they're not (though I would probably just go for `.click()` which to me automatically shows a self-listening node.

Comment: For one thing, why did you break it out into three separate scripts in three separate script tags? Seems excessive.

Comment: @greg `click()` is just alias for `on("click"..)` so it makes no difference.

Comment: @Andrew maybe I wasn't clear, but that's my point entirely. It makes no difference at all. I PERSONALLY use `.click()` just as a quick visual reminder that it's self-listener. I use `.on()` to delegate listeners, so my brain immediately parses out delegated vs. self listeners this way. That's all. ;-)

Comment: Sorry about this - I didn't explain as well as I should of -  we are looking at this page: http://www.steveatattoartist.com - 

I am using hyperlinks to separate and toggle the div's on and off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some extra data attribute and an extra class on your links to make it a little shorter.

So let's say your html looks like this:

```
<div id="white">white</div>
<div id="v2black">v2black</div>
<div id="v3black">v3black</div>

<div id="firstpagename"  class="toggle" data-for="white">toggle white</div>
<div id="secondpagename" class="toggle" data-for="v2black">toggle v2bacl</div>
<div id="thirdpagename"  class="toggle" data-for="v3black">toggle v3black</div>
```

then your jquery can rewritten like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-for');
    $('#' + id).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: here we can also use data function instead attr, like `$(this).data("for")`. jquery looks for data-for attribute in this object.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like we're trying to recreate standard "accordion" behaviour. Depending on the layout of your page, it can be helpful to encapsulate your items if possible. Here is one possible solution to make things that open and close. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRksv/4/)

```
<div id="white" class="panel">
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="v2black" class="panel">    
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="v3black" class="panel">    
    <div class="tab"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>​
<script>
jQuery(".tab").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel').find('.content').toggle();
});​
</script>
```

First we condensed the code into one script tag and one document ready statement, since having it in 3 pieces was only adding bloat.

Then I made sure to chose `$` as the parameter for the doc ready callback. jQuery will kindly pass it one argument `jQuery` so inside our code block we can safely use `$` even if outside our code-block it was reserved for other purposes.

Here the `.tab`s control their `.content` by traversing up to the nearest `.panel` and back down. In this way the same behaviour can control all 3.

If however your "tabs" can't be encapsulated like this you can always associate them to the content they are to show/hide in another way. We'll just need to see your html.

Comment: #firstpagename != #white, #secondpagename != #v2black and so on -> From understand very little from his code. Basically, $(this) is not something he wanted to toggle.

Comment: D'oh, just recognized that this won't work as-is unless you only want to hide it and never show it again. ;-) In which case might as well use `.hide()`. You'll want to include some relationship (maybe the toggle target is structured to be the `next()` element) and then use DOM traversal.

Comment: @GregPettit thanks, I've updated the solution to be "controls" and "content"

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    var White = jQuery("#white").hide();
    jQuery("#firstpagename").on("click", function() {
        White.toggle();

    var Black2 = jQuery("#v2black").hide();
    jQuery("#secondpagename").on("click", function() {
        Black2.toggle();
    });

    var Black3 = jQuery("#v3black").hide();
    jQuery("#thirdpagename").on("click", function() {
        Black3.toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

for the start. If you have many more elements, you might want to loop through a buttonid<>toggleid map:

```
var map = {
    "white": "firstpagename",
    "v2black": "secondpagename",
    ...
};
for (var toggler in map)
    makeToggle(toggler, map[toggler]);
function makeToggle(togglerid, pageid) {
    var page = $(document.getElementById(pageid)).hide();
    $(document.getElementById(togglerid)).click(function() {
        page.toggle();
    });
}
```